# Grouping services so that failure in one restarts them all

Tags: systemd

I have a group of services that are fundamentally linked (ideally they should be ran as a single service/process but that work still needs to be done) in that I want the failure of one service to cause the other services to be restarted as well.

I'm using a target unit to start them all at the same time and I have them all set to `Restart=always` to individually recover but that wouldn't restart the other services if one service failed for any reason.

I thought I might get away with using the `BindsTo` directive which does seem to stop all the services if a single one fails (such as the process being killed).

My service files currently look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=foo
After=syslog.target network.target
BindsTo=foo.service bar.service baz.service all-services.target

[Service]
User=foo
WorkingDirectory=~
Restart=always
RestartSec=90
StartLimitInterval=400
StartLimitBurst=3
SyslogIdentifier=foo
ExecStart=/path/to/binary 
[Install]
WantedBy=all-services.target
```

With a grouping target defined as:

```
[Unit]
Description=all-services
BindsTo=foo.service bar.service baz.service
```

But the `BindsTo` directive seems to completely stop all the services when one fails and never attempt a restart.

I can't seem to find anything that suggests this service group restarting property is achievable directly in systemd rather than restarting a chain of dependencies but I might be missing something (or ignoring a better way of doing this).

Comment: And after ages of head scratching and reading the systemd docs I find the answer just after posting a question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`PartOf`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#PartOf=) directive along with the target unit to start all of the services as a group seems to achieve my goals.

My service files now look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=foo
After=syslog.target network.target
PartOf=foo.service bar.service baz.service all-services.target

[Service]
User=foo
WorkingDirectory=~
Restart=always
RestartSec=90
StartLimitInterval=400
StartLimitBurst=3
SyslogIdentifier=foo
ExecStart=/path/to/binary 
[Install]
WantedBy=all-services.target
```

and the grouping target looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=all-services
PartOf=foo.service bar.service baz.service
```

I can start and restart `foo`, `bar` and `baz` services by running `systemctl start all-services.target` and killing the process used by `foo` causes them all to be stopped and restarted.

One thing that isn't clear is if I run `systemctl stop all-services.target` it will stop all the services but a `systemctl start all-services.target` from the stopped state only starts the target unit instead of all of the services.

I've tried swapping out `WantedBy` to `RequiredBy` in the service units but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement "failure in one restarts them all", a bidirectional `PartOf` between the services and the target is sufficient.

Services:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=all-services.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/binary
Restart=on-failure
```

Target:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=foo.service bar.service baz.service
```

In case a unit fails and restarts, the target will broadcast the restart to all services.

An additional `PartOf` between the services is not necessary. It would only be relevant in cases, when the target is not active.

This [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/808265/941603) gives an explanation, why `BindsTo` is not working in your case.

> Your `foo` unit is using `BindsTo=`, which is meant to track the state of a unit that may *disappear*.

So the `foo` unit will become inactive before it restarts.